# How to access statistics endpoint for a Spark Streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

As of Spark 2.2.0, there's are new endpoints in the API for getting information about streaming jobs.

I run Spark on EMR clusters, using Spark 2.2.0 in cluster mode.

When I hit the endpoint for my streaming jobs, all it gives me is the error message:

> no streaming listener attached to <stream name>

I've dug through the Spark codebase a bit, but this feature is not very well documented. So I'm curious if this is a bug? Is there some configuration I need to do to get this endpoint working?

---

This appears to be an issue specifically when running on the cluster. The same code running on Spark 2.2.0 on my local machine shows the statistics as expected, but gives that error message when run on the cluster.

Comment: There's a handful. The base of the endpoints is `/api/v1/applications/[app-id]/streaming/`, with endpoints for statistics, receivers, batches, etc. See [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) for the full list. Particularly, I'm interested in `/api/v1/applications/[app-id]/streaming/statistics`, but they all have the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, they're all running, and the streaming tab shows up in the web UI as well. Double checked a couple times just to be sure. The only discrepancy that I can think of that might have any impact is that in cluster mode, instead of using `[app-id]`, you use `[app-id]/[attempt-id]`, but I've tried it with and without the attempt id, and with no attempt id it just says there's no such job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the very latest **Spark 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT** built today from the master so *YMMV*. It worked fine.

> Is there some configuration I need to do to get this endpoint working?

No. It's supposed to work fine with no changes to the default configuration.

Make sure the you use the host and port of the driver (as *rumors* are that you could also access `18080` of Spark History Server that does show all the same endpoints, and the same jobs running, but no streaming listener attached).

---

As you can see in the [source code where the error message lives](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/status/api/v1/streaming/ApiStreamingApp.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L50) it can happen only when `ui.getStreamingJobProgressListener` has not been registered (that ends up in `case None`).

So the question now is why would that `SparkListener` not be registered?

That leads us to the [streamingJobProgressListener](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/SparkUI.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L57) var that is set using [setStreamingJobProgressListener](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/SparkUI.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L139) method **exclusively** while `StreamingTab` [is being instantiated](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/ui/StreamingTab.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L41) (which was the reason why I asked you if you can see the Streaming tab).

In other words, if you see the Streaming tab in web UI, you have the streaming metric endpoint(s) available. Check the URL to the endpoint which should be in the format:

```
http://[driverHost]:[port]/api/v1/applications/[appId]/streaming/statistics
```

---

I tried to reproduce your case and did the following that led me to a working case.

1. Started one of the official examples of Spark Streaming applications.

   ```
   $ ./bin/run-example streaming.StatefulNetworkWordCount localhost 9999
   ```

   I did run `nc -lk 9999` first.
2. Opened the web UI @ http://localhost:4040/streaming to make sure the **Streaming** tab is there.

   [image: Streaming tab @ web UI]
3. Made sure http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/ responds with application ids.

   ```
   $ http http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Content-Encoding: gzip
   Content-Length: 266
   Content-Type: application/json
   Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 07:58:04 GMT
   Server: Jetty(9.3.z-SNAPSHOT)
   Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent

   [
       {
           "attempts": [
               {
                   "appSparkVersion": "2.3.0-SNAPSHOT",
                   "completed": false,
                   "duration": 0,
                   "endTime": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.999GMT",
                   "endTimeEpoch": -1,
                   "lastUpdated": "2017-12-13T07:53:53.751GMT",
                   "lastUpdatedEpoch": 1513151633751,
                   "sparkUser": "jacek",
                   "startTime": "2017-12-13T07:53:53.751GMT",
                   "startTimeEpoch": 1513151633751
               }
           ],
           "id": "local-1513151634282",
           "name": "StatefulNetworkWordCount"
       }
   ]
   ```
4. Accessed the endpoint for the Spark Streaming application @ http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/local-1513151634282/streaming/statistics.

   ```
   $ http http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/local-1513151634282/streaming/statistics
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Content-Encoding: gzip
   Content-Length: 219
   Content-Type: application/json
   Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 08:00:10 GMT
   Server: Jetty(9.3.z-SNAPSHOT)
   Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent

   {
       "avgInputRate": 0.0,
       "avgProcessingTime": 30,
       "avgSchedulingDelay": 0,
       "avgTotalDelay": 30,
       "batchDuration": 1000,
       "numActiveBatches": 0,
       "numActiveReceivers": 1,
       "numInactiveReceivers": 0,
       "numProcessedRecords": 0,
       "numReceivedRecords": 0,
       "numReceivers": 1,
       "numRetainedCompletedBatches": 376,
       "numTotalCompletedBatches": 376,
       "startTime": "2017-12-13T07:53:54.921GMT"
   }
   ```

Comment: i have same issue with spark 2.2 but running on a standalone cluster. i do not see Streaming tab. any suggestions to debug further? due to some internal dependencies i can not bump up the version

Comment: I think that you are either looking at the wrong UI (should be the Spark application's not Spark Standalone's) or the Spark app didn't initialize a `StreamingContext`. Either way it's hard to help without more info. Use gist.github.com and add some screenshots? Or just ask a separate question to have the space to include all details.

Comment: I was new to streaming when i came across this question. my confusion was between Structured Streaming vs DStreams. 'Streaming Statistics' UI on port 4040 is specific to DStreams, similar feature is not available out of the box for Structured streaming. Original question could have been more clear if it mentioned DStream.

Comment: @Gowtham Perhaps we need another question from you?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Just go to:
**http://localhost:4040/streaming**

Had a same issue. I ran spark application from Pycharm Python virtual environment. Spark reported that port 4040 was taken:

```
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.100.221:4042
```

but I saw no jobs there and Streaming tab missing.
Then I went to
**http://localhost:4040/streaming**
and behold, everything was there.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of PyCharm in the console window it will show what port it used streaming on. I was assuming it was 4040 but when i checked the output carefully the port was on 4041. Here is the output:

WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.

Then you can use localhost:4041 on any web browser and you should see the streaming output. Hope this helps!