# Missing Streaming tab from the Spark UI

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to test performance of a spark streaming application that I wrote which reads/writes data to Kafka.  Code is working fine but I cannot see the Streaming tab in the UI.  I am using Ambari, but I am assuming this is Spark feature.  I am using Spark 2.2.  Please let me know if I have missed to configure anything.

I tried running the code from the Yarn Client/Yarn Cluster/local mode but same result.  I saw another similar post https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/110212/hdp-26-spark-21-streaming-tab-not-available-in-the.html,  But I am trying to monitor when app is running and from the driver node.  Still the Streaming tab is missing.

My history server is running in 18080 port. And I am running using following http://-node:18080/?showIncomplete=true . But missing the Streaming tab.

I looked at the Spark Streaming code. Wondering if there is version mismatch between Spark and Kafka or something is causing this tab to not appear.  Cannot even find the error "Parent SparkUI to attach this tab to not found!"

[image]

Comment: i am still having the same issue with spark 2.2, check if this post helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47780148/how-to-access-statistics-endpoint-for-a-spark-streaming-application

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's expected issue because Streaming job may lead to huge amount of logs and can not be shown in SparkHS. I can reproduce the issue through SparkHS but there is no reproduce if I go to Spark UI directly using port 4040.

Also, I've found some documentation about this behavior:

https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-one/saas/cdp-one-monitor-and-operate/topics/cdp-one-cm-accessing-the-web-ui-of-a-completed-spark-application.html#pnavId3

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#applying-compaction-on-rolling-event-log-files